# Is it possible to change the background color of directory in powerlevel9k, based on the current vi_mode?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

```
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(dir vi_mode)

POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_HOME_BACKGROUND='green'
POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_HOME_SUBFOLDER_BACKGROUND='green'
POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_DEFAULT_BACKGROUND='green'

POWERLEVEL9K_VI_MODE_INSERT_BACKGROUND="white"
POWERLEVEL9K_VI_MODE_NORMAL_BACKGROUND="blue"
```

I am using the Powerlevel9k theme for zsh shell. Currently, my terminal displays the directory and the vi_mode in the left side prompt. Is it possible to change the background color of the dir based on the vi_mode? Then I would not display the vi_mode on the left prompt saving some space on the terminal. I am guessing some function to get the background color of the directory would be useful, but I am not sure how to find the current vi_mode of the terminal.

Comment: Powerlevel9k is deprecated and unmaintained. You should use Powerlevel10k.